# Problem in editing the element in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dom

I'm working on react-phonebook app. I'm unable to understand the correct logic to edit the contact details.
On clicking the `edit` button, I need to show the form and put name and number of that particular contact in the input fields and then take user input as the edited contact and display it in the list.
I'm facing the following issues:

If `showForm` is false, it gives the error

`Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')`

although I've added `setShowForm(true)` in `handleEdit` function but it still shows error but works when the form is already showing.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let phoneBookData = [{ name: "John Doe", number: 12345678 }];
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(phoneBookData);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    console.log("index:", index);
    let selectedIndex = index;
    let newContacts = contacts.filter(
      (_contact, index) => index !== selectedIndex
    );
    setContacts(newContacts);
  };

  const handleAddContact = () => {
    if (userName.length === 0) {
      alert("Please enter a valid name.");
      return;
    } else if (userName.includes("1")) {
      alert("Name cannot contain any number or special character.");
      return;
    } else if (number.length === 0) {
      alert("Please enter a valid number.");
      return;
    }

    let newContact = { name: userName, number: number };
    setContacts([...contacts, newContact]);
    setUserName("");
    setNumber("");
  };

  const handleEdit = (index) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    document.getElementById("number").value = number;
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
    document.getElementById("name").value = userName;
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4"></div>

          <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="App">
              <h2 className="header">PhoneBook App</h2>
              <span
                style={{
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  color: "blue",
                  textDecoration: "underline",
                }}
                onClick={() => setShowForm(!showForm)}
              >
                {showForm ? "Hide Contact Form" : "Create New Contact"}
              </span>
              {showForm && (
                <div className="container">
                  <form className="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        value={userName}
                        onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                        id="name"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Number"
                        value={number}
                        onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
                        id="number"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-primary icon-holder"
                      onClick={handleAddContact}
                    >
                      Add
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              )}
              <p>There are {contacts.length} contacts saved in this book.</p>
              {contacts.map((contact, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="contacts">
                  <div className="contact-details">
                    <h5>
                      {index + 1}) {contact.name}
                    </h5>
                    <p>{contact.number}</p>
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className="icon-holder"
                    onClick={() => handleEdit(index)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="icon-holder"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleDelete(index);
                    }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/todos-app-listed-rxsd3p?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C51

Answer (score 1):

Don't use DOM selectors like `document.getElementById`.

In your case, the selectors return `null` because the corresponding elements are not yet on the page when you try to select them.

Solution: get rid of the three `document.getElementById` calls, and add the `autoFocus` prop to the field you want to focus.

If you need a reference to an actual DOM element, read into [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

Answer (score 0):

you can manage the form state using React state management and check that the form input are controlled component. When clicking the edit button, populate the form field with the details of the selected contact. Upon updating the contact details, handle the state updates appropriately to reflect the changes in the contact list.
I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you are getting the error:

```
  const handleEdit = (index) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    document.getElementById("number").value = number;
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
    document.getElementById("name").value = userName;
  };
```

You are trying to get form elements of the form that you are not yet showing (async function call most probably) and you consequently get a `null` and you therefore cannot set the `value` of `null`.

Try something like this:

```
  const handleEdit = (index) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    setNumber(number);
    setUserName(userName);
  };
```

and add `autoFocus` to the item you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add useEffect for handling document updating if you want to access DOM elements directly

```js
  useEffect(() => {
     if (showForm) {
        document.getElementById("number").value = number;`
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        document.getElementById("name").value = userName;
    }
  }, [showForm])
```

you can also add refs for better access to DOM elements

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (showForm) {
       numberInputRef.current.value = number;
       usernameInputRef.current.focus();
       usernameInputRef.current.value = userName;
    }
  }, [showForm])
```

this will help you to change the values of inputs automatically every time the showForm state is changed and also ensure the DOM has updated before accesing DOM elements

 
or you can use controlled inputs instead to avoid this kind of bugs

```js
  const handleEdit = useCallback((contact) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    if (contact) {
      setNumber(contact.number);
      setUserName(contact.name);
    }
  }, [setShowForm, setNumber, setUserName]);
```